# What does the property spring.cloud.config.label in Spring Cloud config do?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am learning Spring Cloud Config v3.0.5. When I was studying in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_locating_remote_configuration_resources), I found that the documentation mentioned that

> For instance, you might want to align the config label with your branch but make it optional (in that case, use spring.cloud.config.label=myfeature,develop).

I don’t know what **“align the config label”** means. But I guess it should be to modify the default value of **{label}** in the url (the default value is master)
[image]

However, when i set **spring.cloud.config.label=dev** and visit http://localhost:3344/config-dev.yml, i still get the data on master branch.
[image]


[image]


**So what does the property spring.cloud.config.label do? And what does "align the config label with your branch" mentioned in the document mean?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property `spring.cloud.config.label` can be used in the client application, not in the config server.

I assume that you use a git backend for your config server. To get a config that has the label `dev`, you need to create a branch or tag in the git repository that contains the config. The mechanism for other backends can be looked up in the reference documentation.

After creating the branch, the URLs should work as expected. But please note that the URL `http://localhost:3344/config-dev.yml` refers to an application called `config` and a profile (not a label) `dev`. The default profile of a Spring application is `default` and one of many ways to set it on a client is with the property `spring.profiles.active`.

I agree that the word `align` in the reference documentation is unclear. I think they suggest to create branches in the config repository for feature branch development and use the same branch name for both the config and the code repository, respectively. Then you can set the label to the branch name in the feature branch of the client's code repository.

Comment: I understand the difference between profile and branch, dev is a profile I randomly selected. I'm sorry to have misunderstood you

Comment: I missed the link to the repo before. Sorry! And thanks for the hint.
Does the URL http://localhost:3344/dev/config-dev.yml or http://localhost:3344/config/dev/dev show what you're expecting?

Comment: Thank you @Henning. I didn't know until now that the property spring.cloud.config.label can only be used in client applications. In my previous guess, I thought this property would modify the default value of {label} when used in config server.

Comment: Yes, they all meet my expectations.